# need to retrict maxlength upto 10 for HTML editor in Ext Js

Tags: javascript, extjs

Need to stop entering the letter after 5 . looks like enforceMaxLength and maxLength not working
Please help me if i need to provide any configuration.

```js
 new Ext.panel.Panel({
        title: 'HTML Editor',
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        width: 550,
        height: 250,
        frame: true,
        layout: 'fit',
        items: {
            xtype: 'htmleditor',
            enableColors: false,
            enableAlignments: false,
            enforceMaxLength: true,
            maxLength: 5
        }
    });
```

Comment: Do you want to restrict users to enter only 5 letters in a htmleditor ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason why the question was downvoted was lack of clarity of question and code. Please rephrase the question and use the markdown formatting to show your code. Even better, use a JSFiddle/JSBin or such to show how your code is not working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of extjs are you using ? There is no enforceMaxLength or maxLength for htmleditor. What I think you can do is listen to change event of htmleditor and force disable the component

```
new Ext.panel.Panel({
    title: 'HTML Editor',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    width: 550,
    height: 250,
    frame: true,
    layout: 'fit',
    items: {
        xtype: 'htmleditor',
        enableColors: false,
        enableAlignments: false,
        listeners : {
            change : function(field,newValue, oldValue, eOpts){
                if(newValue.length >= 5 ) {
                    alert('more chars'); // code here for disabling keyboard entry 
                }
            }
        }
    } });
```